# Получение постов пользователей Instagram по API

Tags: instagram-api

Доброго времени суток всем.
Я правильно понял, что сейчас не существует Instagram Api, позволяющего получать посты определённого пользователя (по id, например). Для открытых аккаунтов, разумеется.
Или можно только свои?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Нашли что-нибудь по этой теме?